# "There is the man." Is *there* an adverb or pronoun?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, pronouns, subject-verb-inversion, there-is

According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/there)

> there
>
> 1. adverb
>
> in or at that place (opposed to here ):
>
> *She is there now.*
>
> 7. pronoun
>
> (used to introduce a sentence or clause in which the verb comes before its subject or has no complement):
>
> *There is no hope.*

Then, what element is *there* in:

> There is the man.

I'm confused because "There is the man" is an adverb inversion, in which *there* is an adverb and "the man is" is inverted. But according to the definition above, *there* suddenly becomes a pronoun.

Comment: "There" as an abverb of place can be placed at the beginning of sentences without becoming a pronoun. In #7, "There" doesn't refer to a location; instead, the meaning of the sentence is "Hope does not exist." In "There is the man," "There" is a location (the man is in that spot), so it functions as an adverb.

Comment: Please see my answer again. I seem to have been a little off when I wrote that 'there' is a pronoun in 'There is **a** man/there is some milk'. I've corrected it now (although the main answer is still the same).

Comment: Dummy existential subject, or distal locative (and it is here deictic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this example:

> *There* is **some** milk *in the fridge*.

What would be the question to which you could offer that sentence as an answer?

> 1. Do we have any milk in the fridge?
> 2. Where is **the** milk?

The first one - so, *there is* is used to say that some milk **exists** in the fridge, and therefore it is a *[dummy existential subject](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects)*. As professor Lawler explained below, it doesn't belong to any particular word class or [part of speech](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/word-classes-or-parts-of-speech).

If you ask: *Where is the milk?* Or *Where in the fridge is the milk? I'm looking, but I can't find it.* Your replies would be:

> **The** milk is in the fridge.

Or

> **The** milk is on the top shelf; it's right *there* in front of your nose.

Since we are answering *where* the milk is - *there* is an adverb of place. When we are explaining where something is, the thing has to be specified, hence the definite article.

So **in your example**:

> There is **the** man.

We know which man we are talking about. That one, over there. We are pointing at him, showing his location. So ***there* is an adverb of place.**

If you say:

> There is **a** man (in the street).

This would mean that a man exists in the street - *there* would be a dummy subject in this example.

---

Side notes:

1) I'm not saying that there is a grammar rule by which the use of articles can determine which part of speech 'there' is. But in these examples articles help by clarifying the intended use.

2) A [very interesting article](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/ZAA_final_proof.pdf) about lexical categorisation by G.K. Pullum was recently brought to my attention on ELL. It explains that the way words are categorised in dictionaries often isn't very accurate. So, even though dictionaries include entries for a pronoun 'there', this categorisation can be questioned.

Comment: Nah, they aren't the same word. The distal locative adverb _there_, which contrasts with the proximal locative adverb _here_, is different from, and has a different meaning from, the dummy existential subject _there_ inserted by a syntactic rule. They can be used together, or in contrast: _There's a man there; there's a woman here._ [The rule is called, unsurprisingly, _There_-Insertion,](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/149513/15299) and it has [a number of peculiarities](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105948/15299). Oh, and this _there_ doesn't have a part of speech. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for explaining that! Can 'there', the adverb, and 'there' the dummy subject be called homonyms?

Comment: You can say they're homonyms, or you can say that one (the dummy) developed from the demonstrative (which is true), but no longer has any meaning (which is also true). If you want to say they're homonyms, then you'll hafta also say that _that_ the demonstratie pronoun in _That man is the one_, _that_ the relative pronoun in _the tree that grew in Brooklyn_, and _that_ the tensed complementizer in _I think that I shall never see it_ are also homonyms. Feel free; but there are lots more.

Comment: @JohnLawler I've never thought about it that way, but it makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: I prefer your previous version. :) . . . According to the 2002 H&P *CGEL*, the "there" that is the subject in the existential construction is a dummy pronoun; and that the locative "there" is a preposition. Aside: definite NPs can sometimes be used as the "displaced subject" in the existential, e.g. A: *"I have no milk to use for my recipe. Do you have any?"* B: *"No, I don't. But there is the milk in the neighbor's fridge."*

Comment: @F.E. H&P really have a grudge against adverbs :-). I did find the term dummy pronoun, but one was on Wikipedia (which is useful but can't be fully trusted) and the other on CDO which had a history of disagreement with CGEL (my guess because it's simplified). 'There' is probably one of the things grammarians still have to agree about. I know one thing: when I get a copy of CGEL I'll keep it handy at all times so if ever again someone tells me dismissively: "English is easy" I can smack them on the head with it ;-). Lexical classification in English  is fascinating but it sure isn't easy...

Comment: @F.E. [continued] Thanks for the info :-)! You should probably charge me for all the help I get from you.

Comment: There **are** several proofs that *there* is not the subject of this sentence, and this is one of them.

Comment: @tchrist C'mon, there's no such proofs at all! Do you think CaGEL would argue that if there'd been a ***proof***?! How d'you reckon that's a proof anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

There can be both.

1. There is a tree.
   Here "There" is an adverb.
2. I found a man there . Here "there " is replacing a place noun.

Answer (score -1):

I vote for adverb.  This is just an idiomatic use of an adverbial construction to paraphrase a statement of existence.  It is somewhat similar from this point of view to the German existential "es gibt" "it gives."  There's no question that formally a sentence like "Es gibt einen Mann" is a verbal sentence, but it paraphrases an existential statement "A man exists."