# Noun or adverb function of "There" in "There is X, Y and Z"

Tags: there-is

In the sentence below, is *there* an adverb telling where (giving the location), or a noun as the subject?

> There are many people on the beach.

Comment: "There" is a dummy pronoun functioning as the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246464/there-is-the-man-is-there-an-adverb-or-pronoun

Comment: As also http://english.stackexchange.com/a/200676/15299