# Should I use "is" or "are" in relation to "a ton?"

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

Which is more correct?  There are a ton of jobs on the company's website...OR...There is a ton of jobs on the company's website?  Thanks!

Comment: This is about whether _a ton of jobs_ should be considered singular or plural, and there are good reasons for both positions. That's why we get a lot of questions here about quantifiers. But in this case there's a simpler solution. Since the sentence is phrased with [_There_-Insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105948/15299), a contraction is preferred, and the singular contraction _There's_ is simple to produce, while the plural _There're_ is rare and difficult to pronounce. Since either would work uncontracted, pick the singular and contract it: _There's a ton of jobs there_.

Comment: I am afraid such sloppy/casual expressions as "a ton of jobs" are beyond the help of grammar.

Comment: Replace "ton" with "dozen" or "couple".

Comment: I would say 'tons of' something rather than 'a ton', so the singular/plural question doesn't arise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's "There are a ton of jobs." See, since "jobs" is a plural of "job", you use "are".

Examples:
He (singular) **is** getting a job VS. We (two or more people) **are** getting jobs.

The elephant (singular) **is** taking a bath VS. The elephant*s* (plural) **are** taking baths.

***Make sense?*** B)

Comment: I don't think the usage of is/are is dependent on "jobs", which is the object of the preposition. Directly, you're saying "There is a ton." Just like you'd say "There is a basket of flowers" and not "There are a basket of flowers," because even though "flowers" is plural, you're directly saying "There is a basket." (You would, however, say "There are baskets of flowers." Or "There are baskets of flour"—an uncountable noun this time!)