# There is or there are

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

The English grammar says that we use *there is* when it's a singular noun and *there are* when it's a plural one. 
But I often hear people saying something like "There's also some other words that I'm going to say..."

Could somebody explain what's the matter? Is it something colloquial?

Comment: It's their style of speaking.  Not likely to hear it on the Oxford campus.

Comment: It's lazy speech. It's quicker to say 'There's' than 'There are'. Even those of us who know better are probably guilty on occasion.

Comment: thank you people, just thank you, a lot

Comment: _There is_ does not work the same as [_there's_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105948/15299). Once a verb is contracted, it does not inflect. Therefore it is normal and common and natural and grammatical to say _There's some people here to see you_. The plural _There are_ is almost never contracted, because it's too hard to pronounce correctly, so if you want a contraction, it'll be _there's_, whether the original subject before [_There_-Insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/190345/15299) was singular or plural.

Comment: @JohnLawler - https://books.google.com/books?id=od7fvbnd02MC&pg=PT613&dq=%22there%27re%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirh5C91eDkAhUEJzQIHdRPCU0Q6AEwBXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22there're%22&f=false

Comment: @HotLicks: Notice I said it was hard to **pronounce**. This example is printed and therefore not subject to speech constraints. As you will see if you actually try to pronounce this poem, the contractions of _there are_ distort the meter of the poem with extra syllables, giving a notable [McGonagall](http://www.mcgonagall-online.org.uk/) touch to the stanzas.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I don't listen to myself talking that much, but I *think* I tend to say "threre-ur" when pronouncing "there're", and I've certainly heard other people say it.

Comment: Exactly. There's that extra syllable that _there's_ doesn't have, which thumps like a peg leg through the scansion.